# "SELECT [value]" vs "SELECT [value] FROM [table] LIMIT 1" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Which query is better ?

- `SELECT true;`
- `SELECT true FROM users LIMIT 1;`

In terms of:

- Best practice
- Performance

Comment: They do different things.  Use the one that implements what you really need.

Comment: How they do different things ? they output the same result

Comment: no they don't first gets one result second all rows that you have with the value true

Comment: In what situation would you need to actually use either of those queries? It seems remarkably wasteful.

Comment: If the users table is empty (has no records), the second query will return nothing.

Comment: @Martin I asked this question to know if there are any performance or other differences between two

Comment: You shouldn't waste effort on performance till you know what you are doing, and till the project requires it. That said, query 1 always returns one row from computing the query and query 2 reads the table `users`, returning one row true or zero rows. So the neither question makes sense here.

Comment: If there is at most 1 row, they are identical and the performance difference is negligible.  If there is more than 1 row, the question is not relevant.

Comment: Please come back with a realistic pair of queries; we would be happy to give you a more civilized answer.

Comment: @RickJames thank you for your interest to answer my question, all what I wanted to know is to see if in a query like this will mysql query parser ignore the part about the table to save performance or not. Bill Karwin made it clear to me, thank you too. sorry for not making my question clear enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query has less overhead because it doesn't reference any tables.

```
mysql> explain select true\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: NULL
   partitions: NULL
         type: NULL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
     filtered: NULL
        Extra: No tables used
```

Whereas the second query does reference a table, which means it has to spend time:

- Checking that the table exists and if the query references any columns, check that the columns exist.
- Checking that your user has privileges to read that table.
- Acquiring a metadata lock, so no one does any DDL or LOCK TABLES while your query is reading it.
- Starting to do an index-scan, even though it will be cut short by the LIMIT.

Here's the explain for the second query for comparison:

```
mysql> explain select true from mysql.user limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 276
          ref: NULL
         rows: 8
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
```

Comment: The important part here is that you can let the server analyse queries.

Comment: @TheDudeWithHat yes, that's from the reasons I accepted Bill's answer. Thanks Bill. All what I wanted to know is to analyse the two queries and figure out performance differences and will mysql query parser ignore the part about the table or not.

Answer (score 1):

First query will one row with value true.
Second query will return all the rows from users table but true as only value.

So you if you need one row user first query. But if you need all the rows with same value then use second one.

Answer (score 1):

In either case, it is obvious you want the value of TRUE :) With this intention, the "SELECT TRUE" is the most efficient as it won't cause MySQL to go further looking for users table, no matter how many rows in it, and then go even further with "LIMIT 1" if there are rows!

By the term BEST PRACTICE, I am not sure what you meant here, because, from my point of view, this doesn't even require a PRACTICE, let alone BEST, as I fail to see any real life application of this approach.